Google Sheets - not getting desired result using SUMIFS, QUERY or ARRAYFORMULA
I have details of meals ordered in the "Meal Order Sheet". I wish to sum the number of Add-on orders in "Meal Order Sheet"!J: J in another sheet for items listed in the column "Meal Order Sheet"!I:I. I used SUMIFS, QUERY formula, and ARRAYFORMULA and I am not getting the desired results.
Sample "Meal Order Sheet"!Cx:Mx

=sumifs('Meal Order Sheet'!J:J,'Meal Order Sheet'!I:I,I3, 'Meal Order Sheet'!C:C,$F$1,'Meal Order Sheet'!L:L,$B$2)

I am always getting a result "0" (Zero).
Using either of these
=QUERY('Meal Order Sheet'!A:L, "SELECT SUM(J) WHERE I = '"&I3&"' AND C = '"&$F$1&"' AND L = '"&$B$2&"'", 1)

=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY('Meal Order Sheet'!A:L, "SELECT SUM(J) WHERE I = '"&I3&"' AND C = '"&$F$1&"' AND L = '"&$B$2&"'", 1))

I always get the header in cell 'Meal Order Sheet'!J1, which is "No of Add-ons".
Using formula
=QUERY('Meal Order Sheet'!A:L, "SELECT SUM(J) WHERE I = '"&I3&"' AND C = '"&$F$1&"' AND L = '"&$B$2&"'", 0)

I am always getting result "SUM".
What is the correct formula that I should use?

Your sumifs() formula seems correct in structure. Did you check criteria carefully? Do you have correct data as per criteria? Share a sample work book or post data to your post as text table and show your desired output.

what is in I3? It looks like it's empty. [Edit] your question to include sample data in markdown text, not an image.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. And just in case you're tempted to just add a link, from the start of the [tag:google-sheets] tag wiki: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.

share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Thank you Harun24hr, Blindspots and Ken White. Based on your responses I verified and realised that the 'Meal Order Sheet'!J:J column was not in Number Format. After changing the format to number, the formula is working fine.

While the SUMIFS function works fine, the QUERRY formula still gives erroneous results, as mentioned above. Sharing a link to my Google Sheets (sample data) for verification  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KPqgBGrUp6s2adIOlUOoNq45SdydQS3aNpi_OOW1SC8/edit?usp=sharing
The formulae are in the J column of "KItchen Dasboard" sheet

The shared test sheet has restricted access. try with =QUERY('Meal Order Sheet'!A:L, "SELECT sum(J) WHERE I = '"&I3&"' AND C = date '"&text(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND L = '"&$B$2&"' label sum(J) ''", 0)

Sorry, rockinfreakshow, have removed the restricted access. Tried the suggested formula and getting error message "Query completed with an empty output" - the sumifs is giving correct result. Maybe I should change the date format used !!!


You may try:
=QUERY('Meal Order Sheet'!A:L, "SELECT sum(J) WHERE I = '"&I3&"' AND C = date '"&text(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND lower(L) = lower('"&$B$2&"') label sum(J) ''", 0)


